# how can i rotate chart in c#

Tags: c#, .net, charts

hello everyone I need help please how can I rotate a chart from horizontal bar chart to vertical bar chart

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Sql" Width="700px">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="BusinessLine" YValueMembers="% Completed" ChartType ="Column"
></asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisX Interval="1" TextOrientation="Rotated90">
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: Please describe your issue more thoroughly. What have you tried to solve the issue on your own? What problems did you encounter? Please see [ask] and [mcve]on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the [`ChartType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype(v=vs.110).aspx) from `Column` :

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="BusinessLine" 
                           YValueMembers="% Completed" ChartType ="Column">
```

to `Bar`:

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="BusinessLine" 
                           YValueMembers="% Completed" ChartType ="Bar">
```

Note that `Columns` are **vertical** and `Bars` are **horizontal**. Your question suggests something else..